# setBackgroundImage not working as expected with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm trying to follow [the Fabric.js tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1) to `setBackgroundImage` to one of a few images I have associated with the buttons and am getting some weirdness. Basically, the buttons 1 and 3 are both slow/unresponsive/take two clicks to take effect, and button two doesn't want to load locally or via Imgur. Anyways, I'm using Fabric.js v. 1.7.22 and jQuery 3.3.1.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.setHeight(400);
canvas.setWidth(400);

$("#one").click(function(event) {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/honey_im_subtle.png');
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$("#two").click(function(event) {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/4Ut8gsw.png');
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$("#three").click(function(event) {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/2S08Y3b.jpg');
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddd;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="one">
One
</button>

<button id="two">
Two
</button>

<button id="three">
Three
</button>
```

What is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setBackgroundImage](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setBackgroundImage) accepts three arguments.

1. url
2. callback
3. options for image.

call `renderAll()` inside the callback.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.setHeight(400);
canvas.setWidth(400);

$("#one").click(function(event) {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/honey_im_subtle.png',function(){
   canvas.renderAll();
  },{
   width:canvas.width,
   height:canvas.height
  });
});

$("#two").click(function(event) {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/4Ut8gsw.png',function(){
   canvas.renderAll();
  },{
   width:canvas.width,
   height:canvas.height
  });
});

$("#three").click(function(event) {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/2S08Y3b.jpg',function(){
   canvas.renderAll();
  },{
   width:canvas.width,
   height:canvas.height
  });
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddd;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="one">
One
</button>

<button id="two">
Two
</button>

<button id="three">
Three
</button>
```